# Big Commerce API - Update Product Custom Field - 422 Error

Tags: api, product, bigcommerce

I'm trying to build an integration for a client between Big Commerce and their ERP system. As part of this, I need to update existing custom fields against products in Big Commerce.

The API reference (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/catalog/product-custom-fields/updatecustomfield) states that this is possible. I have built the integration code to use the exact method described in the API reference but it keeps returning a 422 error which says:
**The custom field with the name: xxxxxxxxx & value: yyyyyy already exists.**

I don't understand why it would give this error; I know it exists, that's why I'm updating it. If it didn't exist, I would be using the Create Custom Field method instead.

Anyone ever come across this issue before or know why this may be occurring?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I just tested this by modifying a product custom field on my personal store and was successful in making the change to both name and value. Have you tested other products/custom fields to test out if it could be product specific?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the API to be fairly robust, and use the custom_field API a LOT.

Have you done a quick check, via the API to get ALL the custom_fields for the product you are trying to update the custom_field for, and make sure you are updating by the correct custom_field ID? (so, not trying to change a different custom_field, which will then cause this error to be raised?)